# Oracle Self Constructor function with if statment

Tags: oracle, plsql

My question is as i am new with oracle and pl/sql that is it possible to check the values during inserting by using self constructor.
Example checking number of a varray items depending on another attribute value?

```
Create or Replace Type test_arr as Varray(20) of number;

Create or Replace Type test_typ as Object(
tID number(5),
tType varchar2(1),
tArray test_arr
);
```

I would like to test when tType='A' then tArray.count should be less then 2 and if the tType='B' then tArray.count should be between 5 and 20.
I would like to test this during the insert process so:

```
Create Table test_tbl of test_typ;
Insert Into test_tbl Values(187,'A',test_arr(1,6,7)); /*This should give an error and not insert the record as the tType is 'A' and the tArray has 3 values!*/
```

I am not sure if i could do that with self return. The main thing here is that i need to check during the insert process!

I would appropriate any help. Thanks!

Comment: A type constructor will not help here. Firstly, you can only add constructors, and not change the default one, so your custom validating constructor would have to have a signature other than `(tID, tType, tArray)`. Secondly, an `insert` into the relational presentation of an object table does not invoke its type's constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done using trigger

```
create trigger instrg BEFORE INSERT ON test_tbl
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF  :NEW.tType = 'A' AND :NEW.tArray.COUNT >= 2 then  
       RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001, 'error 1');
    ELSIF  :NEW.tType = 'B' AND  :NEW.tArray.COUNT NOT BETWEEN 5 AND 20 then
        RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001, 'error 2');
    END IF;
END;
```

Look at `if else` conditions and I think you easily understand what conditions are there, and you can also modify they, if you need.

Comment: yes i know if condition. I did the task using a procedure and call it with declare begin call_procedure() end stuff but i need to use this with sql only. actually i did not know this trigger things so i will have a look on that. tnx

Comment: I have tried the trigger. Exactly what i needed. It works perfectly with the other restrictions as well i placed there. Thank you so much!